# Creating Windows VM using Image (.VHD) from CLI in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure

I am expericing problem with the new portal of Azure in creating Image and then creating VM from that image. 
Although using some help 
"https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-capture-image/#comments" I could create a image using CLI but while creating a VM from that image there were few commands which are throwing error. Need help in that

As given in the link document :

```
$vnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -AddressPrefix $vnetAddressPrefix -Subnet $subnetconfig
```

My Version :

```
$vnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name myvirtualnetwork -ResourceGroupName my_Resource_Group -Location southus -AddressPrefix 10.0.0.0/** -Subnet 10.0.0.0/**
```

** -> some number

Below is the error which I am getting in power shell :

```
New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork : Cannot bind parameter 'Subnet'. Cannot convert the "10.0.0.0/**" value of type
"System.String" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSSubnet".
At line:1 char:153
+ ... 0.0/16 -Subnet 10.0.0.0/**
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.NewAzureVirtualNetworkCommand
```

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is, it wants a pssubnet object, rather than a string - take a look at `New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig`

Answer (score 0):

The parameter **-Subnet** expects a variable of type "*Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSSubnet*". That is, instead of directly passing the subnet as a string you have to pass an object.

Try (make sure to change parameters accordingly):

```
$VnetName = "MyVNET"
$AddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/24"
$SubnetName = "Subnet-1"
$SubnetPrefix = "10.0.0.0/27"
$ResouceGroup = "MyRG"
$Location = "eastus"

$subnetconfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $SubnetName -AddressPrefix $SubnetPrefix

$vnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $VnetName -ResourceGroupName $ResouceGroup -Location $Location -AddressPrefix $AddressPrefix -Subnet $subnetconfig
```

Btw:

"southus" is not a valid location. Use Get-AzureRmLocation to list all available

"10.0.0.0/**" is not a valid prefix. You have to define the correct network segment to use.

Comment: Now getting error while executing this "$nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $nicname -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id"

Comment: Errors Says : is referencing public IP address